# How to display Lync conversation window in "pending" state?

Tags: c#, lync

This seems pretty basic, but I couldn't find on the web how to do this.

I have the following code:

```
public static void StartChatWithUser(Microsoft.Lync.Model.Contact imContact, string title = null)
{
    try
    {
        var lyncClient = Microsoft.Lync.Model.LyncClient.GetClient();

        var conversation = lyncClient.ConversationManager.AddConversation();
        conversation.AddParticipant(imContact);
        if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(title))
        {
            conversation.Properties[Microsoft.Lync.Model.Conversation.ConversationProperty.Subject] = title;
        }
        var im = conversation.Modalities[Microsoft.Lync.Model.Conversation.ModalityTypes.InstantMessage];
        if (im.CanInvoke(Microsoft.Lync.Model.Conversation.ModalityAction.Connect))
        {
            im.BeginConnect((ar) => { if (ar.IsCompleted) { ((Microsoft.Lync.Model.Conversation.InstantMessageModality)ar.AsyncState).EndConnect(ar); } }, im);
        }
    }
    catch( Exception x )
    {
        //Handle exception
    }
}
```

This "sort-of" works, since it opens the contact window and starts a chat - meaning the other side is requested to join the chat.

Is there a way for me to open the Conversation Window without initiating the chat with the other user (I want it the same way as when I double click a user in the Lync contact list).

posted the same question at the Lync Client Dev. TechNet forum: http://lksz.me/s8Yn8a.

Thanks in advance.

---

## My final result

Thanks to the answer provided by MOHAMED A. SAKAR and ckeller, I fixed my code, and here is my new method.
Thanks guys

The following using clause is needed:

```
using Microsoft.Lync.Model.Extensibility;
```

And here is the new code:

```
public static void StartChatWithUser(Microsoft.Lync.Model.Contact imContact, string title = null)
{
    try
    {
        var lyncAutomation = Microsoft.Lync.Model.LyncClient.GetAutomation();

        var inviteeList = new string[] { imContact.Uri };
        var modalitySettings = new Dictionary<AutomationModalitySettings, object>();
        modalitySettings.Add(AutomationModalitySettings.SendFirstInstantMessageImmediately, false);
        if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(title))
        {
            modalitySettings.Add(AutomationModalitySettings.Subject, title);
        }

        lyncAutomation.BeginStartConversation(
            AutomationModalities.InstantMessage,
            inviteeList,
            modalitySettings,
            (ar) => { if (ar.IsCompleted) { ((Automation)ar.AsyncState).EndStartConversation(ar); }},
            lyncAutomation);
    }
    catch( Exception x )
    {
        //Handle exception
    }
}
```

Comment: You're probably better off asking on the Lync forum, as the Lync audience here is rather limited. Here's the link: http://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/ocsclients/threads

Comment: thanks I'll try that, if I get an answer, I'll post it here

Comment: @Polynomial : it seems stackoverflow was the right place to post the question after all, the Lync Dev Forum is still silent on the subject.
Though I'll now post the info there too.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you should first create Dictionary of AutomationModalitySettings and their values:

```
private Dictionary<AutomationModalitySettings, object> _modalitySettings;
```

After that you should initiate these modalities:

```
_modalitySettings = new Dictionary<AutomationModalitySettings, object>();
_modalitySettings.Add(AutomationModalitySettings.SendFirstInstantMessageImmediately, false);
```

after that you could initiate the call

```
_asyncResult = _automation.BeginStartConversation(
             _chosenMode,
             _inviteeList,
             _modalitySettings,
             null,
             null);
```

I hope this helps you

Comment: Thanks guys this is perfect, I'm adding another answer with my complete fixed code, "for prosperity", but your answer hit the mark perfectly.